# skype bot searchable issue

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I have created a skype bot and the bot is published. But I cannot add the skype bot in to my contacts because it will not appear while I searching in skype. How can I get my bot in skype search?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not published your bot on skype you can not add it as a contact by searching for it. To add a bot to your skype contact you need to visit the azure portal -> bot service -> channels -> skype.

[image]

This will redirect you to a page where you can add this bot as a contact.

[image]

Click on the add to contact.

**You can also add the bot to skype contact by simply visiting the link https://join.skype.com/bot/Your-Bot-Id**